# I must give the programm an argument and it must make the root of it with the "heron process" also it must have 30 decimals

Tags: c#

```
 public static BigDecimal bessereZieheWurzel(int zahl){
    BigDecimal bessereZahl = new BigDecimal(zahl);
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(zahl);
    BigDecimal zwei = new BigDecimal(2);
    BigDecimal endErg = bessereZahl;
    BigDecimal zwischenErg = new BigDecimal(0);
    BigDecimal epsilon = new BigDecimal(0.000000000000000000000000000001);
    int anzahlSchritte = 1;
    BigDecimal variable = new BigDecimal(zahl);

    zwischenErg = bessereZahl.divide(x,30, RoundingMode.DOWN).add(x);

    zwischenErg = zwischenErg.divide(zwei,30, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    BigDecimal letzterDurchlauf = zwischenErg;
    x=zwischenErg;



    while(letzterDurchlauf.subtract(endErg).compareTo(epsilon) == 1);

    endErg = variable.divide(x,30, RoundingMode.DOWN).add(x);

    endErg = endErg.divide(zwei,30, RoundingMode.DOWN);


    anzahlSchritte ++;



      return endErg;
```

My problem is that my while isn't right. I dont know whats wrong there. How can I change the while to get the right thing?

Comment: Your `while` is empty. `while` takes a block `{ }`, you've just given it a single empty statement `;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(letzterDurchlauf.subtract(endErg).compareTo(epsilon) == 1);
```

What is going on in this line of code? 
The answer is: nothing. Absolutely nothing. 
To fix this run it like so:

```
while(letzterDurchlauf.subtract(endErg).compareTo(epsilon) == 1)
{
    //Stuff you want to run goes in here
}
```

Now your while loop will work correctly.